# How to balance resistance between speaker wires made of copper fabric?

Tags: amplifier, audio, resistance, wire, speakers

I'm working on an art installation where the speaker wires are made of a copper fabric material, a relatively high resistance material. I understand this is not ideal for speakers, but due to aesthetics, I'm trying to see if I can keep this same material without compromising quality/efficiency and the life span of amplifier/speaker.

This is a stereo system and audio's spatial effects are very important. Currently, the sound output is fine, it works with no issues, however, one speaker seems quieter than the other. The speaker's fabric wires are of different lengths, thus I'd like to 'balance' the resistance so both speakers have the same power distribution.

The amplifier is a typical **PAM8403** stereo class D amp and its powered by **5V**. The speakers are rated **3W 4Ohms**.

These are the readings I get from a multimeter (amplifier to speaker connection):

- **Speaker 1+** = 2 ohms
- **Speaker 1-** = 1.5 ohms
- **Speaker 2+** = 3.9 ohms
- **Speaker 2-** = 4.8 ohms

And if I place the probes in between + and - near the amplifier connections:

- **Speaker 1 =** 6.5 ohms
- **Speaker 2 =** 12 ohms

The second speaker has a much longer fabric wire, thus the higher resistance. I understand PAM8403 is rated for 4ohms speakers, but would it be OK for it to drive 12ohms?

And to balance the resistance, could I add a 5W resistor in series for speaker 1? What would be best, to add 5.5 ohms on the + line for a total resistance of 12 ohms, or would I need to add resistors to + and - lines, for both speakers, so everything is balanced?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, just add a single 5.5-ohm, 5 watt resistor in series with one of the leads to speaker 1. There's no need to worry about "balance".

Comment: yes or double up the fabric wires to speaker 2 to halve their resistance.

Comment: thanks both, I think I will go with the resistor solution as I can't change the length of the fabric wire. Will the pam8403 be fine with 12ohm resistance?

Comment: @Chu what Jasen meant is that you could run two (four) wires to the second speaker to halve resistance. (Not changing length, just running double "thickness".)

Comment: @JYelton thank you, I see now. But still, that's not possible, there is no more space for wires there. The resistor will do alright! :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be just to adjust the gain of your audio amp so that the left and right speakers are balanced.